# RightMove Array - Insert column tItles and values MySQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm getting very stuck on something that should be very easy. I am trying to parse a .BLM file using a PHP class from http://kodegeek.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/rightmove-data-parsing-php-class/

The Class works perfectly and outputs an array like this: -

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [AGENT_REF] => _70 [ADDRESS_1] => 123 Main Street [POSTCODE1] => CF12 [POSTCODE2] => 4HY [FEATURE1] => Ideal Location [FEATURE2] => Only £250 per room [FEATURE3] => Three Double Bedrooms ) [2] => Array ( [AGENT_REF] => _83 [ADDRESS_1] => 45 Harriet Street [POSTCODE1] => CF24 [POSTCODE2] => 4BU [FEATURE1] => Modern [FEATURE2] => Laminate Flooring ) )
```

Once the array is created I want to immediately insert the array into a SQL table. Ideally this would grab the Field titles eg. [AGENT_REF] [ADDRESS_1] and create columns and insert the data as a new row per array ([0] => Array [2] => Array) etc.

I have tried something like this and a multitude of other variation and I cant seem to get it to work.

```
function mysql_insert_array($table, $rmdata) {
foreach ($rmdata as $field=>$value) {
 $fields[] = '`' . $field . '`';
 $values[] = "'" . $value . "'";

}
$field_list = join(',', $fields);
$value_list = join(', ', $values);



$query = "INSERT INTO testarray (" . $field_list . ") VALUES (" . $value_list . ")";
```

Comment: You'll have to put your single values in quotes - just separating them by comma is not enough.

Comment: What about if some are the values are NULL?

Comment: Where do you populate the $values array? (not that it is a mindbreaker)

Comment: You'll have to use a foreach loop. If $field is set and $value is empty or not set, you'll have to decide what to do. Set a (default/NULL) value or exclude the field from the INSERT query and instead let the database enter the default value for this field.

Comment: Ok, now im just getting "NULL" values through to my table, except for the "[0] => Array" & [1] => Array & [2] => Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$rmdata = ARRAY();

$rmdata[0]['field1'] = 1;
$rmdata[0]['field2'] = 'two';
$rmdata[0]['field3'] = 3;
$rmdata[0]['field4'] = NULL;
$rmdata[0]['field5'] = 'five';
$rmdata[1] = $rmdata[2] = $rmdata[3] = $rmdata[0];

foreach ($rmdata AS $key => $dummy) {

  $fields = ARRAY();
  $values = ARRAY();

  foreach ($rmdata[$key] as $field=>$value) {
    if (!isset($value)) {
      //$value='';
      // or
      //if($field=='field4') { $value=4; }
      // or $values[] = "NULL";
    }

    if (isset($value)) {
      $fields[] = $field;
      $values[] = "'".$value."'";
    }
  }
  // if (count($fields) > 0)
  echo 'key: '.$key.'<br />';
  $sql_fields = implode(',', $fields);
  $sql_values = implode(',', $values);
  print_r($sql_fields); echo '<br />';
  print_r($sql_values); echo '<hr />';

}    

?>
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly!! Awesome work! One problem is that in the array values sometimes "'" characters are used.. e.g. [example]=> It's a lovely day. This is causing an SQL error because of the "'"  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You must create table with the field list before insert.
If you dont have table created, you can use :

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists TABLENAME ( 
    id tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    AGENT_REF varchar(80) NOT NULL, 
    ADDRESS_1 varchar(255),
    POSTCODE1 varchar(6),
    POSTCODE2 varchar(6),
    FEATURE1 varchar(255),
    FEATURE2 varchar(255),
    FEATURE3 varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
    )"; 

mysql_query($sql,$link);
```

and after your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rmdata = ARRAY();

$rmdata['field1'] = 1;
$rmdata['field2'] = 'two';
$rmdata['field3'] = 3;
$rmdata['field4'] = NULL;
$rmdata['field5'] = 'five';

$fields = ARRAY();
$values = ARRAY();
foreach ($rmdata as $field=>$value) {
  if (!isset($value)) {
    //$value='';
    // or
    //if($field=='field4') { $value=4; }
    // or $values[] = "NULL";
  }

  if (isset($value)) {
    $fields[] = $field;
    $values[] = "'".$value."'";
  }

}

// if (count($fields) > 0)
$sql_fields = implode(',', $fields);
$sql_values = implode(',', $values);
```

Comment: The problem is this only returns "INSERT INTO RMDATATABLE (`0`,`1`,`2`) VALUES ('Array','Array','Array')"

Comment: Maybe its because the Array im trying to work with starts like this..Array ( [0] => Array ( [AGENT_REF] => _70 [ADDRESS_1] => 78

Comment: Then you have to go through each of your $rmdata ARRAY, so if you use your data, you have to change my code above to foreach($rmdata[0] ... and if you really have more then one row ($rmdata[0]=ARRAY(...), $rmdata[1] = ARRAY(...) you have to put the shown foreach in an other foreach, using the index as e.g. $key like $rmdata[$key] = ARRAY(...)

Comment: That sounds perfect @djot i will give it a try!